# Proving that $\lambda_a:G\to G$ is a permutation of the set $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the following task:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $a$ be a fixed element of G. Show that the map $\lambda_a:G \to G$, given by $\lambda_a(g) = ag$ for $g \in G$, is a permutation of the set $G$.

While I feel fairly positive that what I have written down is correct, I am insecure as to how valid the argument is for the proof itself:

We know that $\lambda_a:G \to G$ and $g \mapsto ag$. Since $a, g \in G$, then $ag \in G$, by the definition of a group. Assume, for the sake of simplicity, that $G$ is finite. We have that  $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
    g_1 & g_2 & g_3 & \cdots & g_{n-1} & g_{n-1} \\
    ag_1 & ag_2 & ag_3 & \cdots &  ag_{n-1}  & ag_n
  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$. We must have that $ag_x = g_y$ for some $x, y$ by the definition of a group. Thus, the map $\lambda_a: G \to G$ is a permutation. Note that $G$ does not need to be finite for the argument to hold.

Comment: To avoid the assumption of finiteness, remember that a permutation is just a bijective map from a set to itself. Note that the inverse of this map has essentially the same form, only for a different choice of $a$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that (I believe that) "unassuming" finiteness does not hurt the argument.

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need to assume that $G$ is finite. You know it's surjective since $a(a^{-1}g)=g$. Moreover, if $ag=ah$, then $g=h$ by cancellation. Therefore you have a (set) automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I don't need the assumption, I simple think the permutation table is prettier that way. As far as I am able to see, it does not hurt my argument either way, correct?

Comment: It does hurt your argument, in that you cannot generalise to infinite groups that way. For instance, if $G=\mathbb Z$, $a=2$, then you have an infinite permutation $(1\,2\,4\,8\,16\ldots)$ that you can't actually write down, and that doesn't even describe all of $\lambda_2$.

Comment: I can't say that I follow. Consider $$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
   \cdots g_1 & g_2 & g_3 & \cdots &\\
   \cdots ag_1 & ag_2 & ag_3 & \cdots &
  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$$

with the same argument as in the OP. How does this hurt the argument?

Comment: Sorry, my above example was wrong and I should correct it. It should look like $(\ldots-2\,0\,2\,4\,6\ldots)$, but the point that there is more than one orbit is still there. You can't write down all of $\lambda_2$ by writing down one cycle.

Comment: Of course you can't. You can, however, write down the permutation table, assuming that one is of a faith where three dots is a valid representation of infinity.

Comment: If you don't mind, then you don't mind. My method is simpler in that you don't have to write anything down.

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that the map $\lambda_a$ that takes $g$ to $ag$ is a bijection from the group $G$ to itself.  Given any element $b$, by the basic properties of groups, the equation $ax=b$ has a solution.  Hence, $\lambda_a$ is onto.  Also, if $ax=ay$, then $x=y$ by the cancellation property of groups.  Thus, $\lambda_a$ is a permutation.